# How to fix issue of variables being referenced before assignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics, astronomy

I'm having some issues with this code as the final line seems to be causing an issue:

```
from astropy.io import fits

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob  
import pdb #to debug

filelist=glob.glob('5/img/*.fit') #reads in all fits files

hdu = fits.open('MCtest_C1.fits')
hdu[0].header
coeff=hdu[0].data #added in [1].data
print(coeff.shape)
hdu.close()


def make_cube(filelist,x0,x1,y0,y1):
    exptime= np.zeros(len(filelist))
    n=np.zeros(len(filelist))
    jd= np.zeros(len(filelist))
    #pdb.set_trace() #- used to debug

    for i,name in enumerate(filelist):
        hdu=fits.open(name)
        img=hdu[1].data
        nonlin = coeff[:,:,0]*img**3 + coeff[:,:,1]*img**2 + coeff[:,:,2]*img**1 + coeff[:,:,3]*img**0
        exptime[i]=hdu[0].header['EXPTIME']
        n[i]=int( (hdu[0].header['RUNSET'].split(':') )[0] )
        jd[i]=hdu[0].header['JD']
        hdu.close()
        img=img[x0:x1,y0:y1] #makes cutout
        idx=(n>3) #added 13/10/17
        if (i==0):
            cube=img.copy()
        else:
            cube=np.dstack((cube,img))
        print (n[i],i,cube.shape)

    print(n,cube.shape)
    idx=(n>3)
    hdu=fits.PrimaryHDU(cube[:,:,idx])
    hdu.writeto(  ('cube_corrected_%i_%i_%i_%i.fits' % (x0,x1,y0,y1)  ) ,overwrite=True )
    hdu=fits.PrimaryHDU(exptime[idx])
    hdu.writeto(  ('exptime_corrected_%i_%i_%i_%i.fits' % (x0,x1,y0,y1)  ) ,overwrite=True )
    hdu=fits.PrimaryHDU(jd[idx])
    hdu.writeto(  ('jd_corrected_%i_%i_%i_%i.fits' % (x0,x1,y0,y1)  ) ,overwrite=True )
    hdu=fits.PrimaryHDU(nonlin[idx])
    hdu.writeto(  ('nonlin_corrected_%i_%i_%i_%i.fits' % (x0,x1,y0,y1)  ), overwrite=True)

make_cube(filelist, 0, 512, 0, 512)
```

The error is as follows: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cube' referenced before assignment`

I have tried different indentation of the final line, and it runs with different indentation but it doesn't run the code properly.

I've also looked up other issues associated with this error but I haven't seen anything that could help me.

Any help would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: If `filelist` is empty, you never enter your `for` loop, therefore `cube` is never assigned

Comment: Thank you very much! That seemed to have sorted it out!

Comment: Since this just a minor mistake I would suggest you to remove the question, as I don't see how this could be relevant to anyone else.